# Data truncated for column, but the data truncated is a empty C#/MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert values in a MySql table through C#. My string cmdText to send to MySql in the final stage is like that:

```
INSERT INTO sistema1 (*some columns here*, AktivesTeam, *another columns here*) 
                                   VALUES (*values here*,'',*more values here*)
```

The problem is in the AktivesTeam column. The column is set as Double and the value that I'm trying to input is empty. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see null, I see empty string.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought they were the same. Edited =) Thanks

Comment: no problem. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a typo. what do you want the value to be? null or 0? those are your two options.

Comment: I want the value null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:** if your column `AktivesTeam` supports `NULL` values you can leave that column while inserting values.

Try This: skip the `AktivesTeam` column name and value

```
INSERT INTO sistema1 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) VALUES (VALUE1,VALUE2);
```

**Solution 2:** if your column `AktivesTeam` does not support `NULL` values you can insert default `double` value `0.0`

Try This:

```
INSERT INTO sistema1 (COLUMN1,AktivesTeam , COLUMN2) VALUES (VALUE1,0.0,VALUE2);
```

**Suggestion:** You need to use *parameterised queries* to avoid *SQL injection attacks*

Comment: how do can I do in a situation that I have three columns:
INSERT INTO sistema1 (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3) VALUES (VALUE1,,VALUE3);
This?
Thanks!

Comment: @RafaelCampos: can rephrase your question again? you wanted to insert `null` for second column? if yes then you just skip the second column name and value.

Comment: It worked =) I had to change my code a little bit but it worked fine. Thanks! And I'm sorry for my English

Comment: Glad tobe help of you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have some mapping logic to map to/from the database to your object model.

Since it appears your object model allows for `AktivesTeam` to be an empty string or null, your mapping logic can accommodate the change to/from the database.

If you're using parameterized queries, it might look something like this:

```
parameters.AddParameter("?AktivesTeam ", string.IsNullOrEmpty(myModel.AktivesTeam) ? 0.0 : Convert.ToDouble(myModel.AktivesTeam));
```

If your column supports NULL values you could replace 0.0 with NULL.